# excel increment absolute reference every x rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to increment an absolute reference every 60 rows by 1.

cell reference is `'Country List'!$A$2` for the first 60 rows in column D.

So I can use `='Country List'!$A$2` and then manually increment it to `='Country List'!$A$3` at line 61.

Is there a way to fill the entire column with the reference expressed differently that will auto increment the `$A$2` every 60 rows to save me having to change it hundreds of times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify this in Excel (I use LO Calc and there are sometimes minor differences in functions):

```
=INDIRECT("'Country List'!$A$"&2+INT((ROW()-1)/60))
```

INDIRECT builds a cell reference from the text and formula.  This assumes the values start in row 1.  If it starts in a different row, you'll need to tweak this (instead of subtracting `1` from the row, subtract the number of the first row).

Comment: Brilliant worked just as you suggested with the change you mentioned:

Comment: In Excel, you can replace `ROW()` with `ROWS($1:1)` to make the formula work in any starting row,